# Using GWT with Enterprise JavaBeans

Tags: java, gwt, ejb-3.0

I need to build frontend using GWT and use EJB as backend technology, but i am not able to find out enough information on how to go about it . It will be really good if some one can guide me through the procedure once

thanks

Comment: Look into GWT request factory. It seems like it would be conducive to using EJB. (But I haven't done it)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want to check out this little tutorial: [GWT Integration
An attempt to share some of the things I have learned using GWT, JBoss, HTML5, and JPA.](http://jamies-gwt.blogspot.de/2010/03/walkthrough-integrating-gwt-with-jboss.html)

The author builds a small GWT / EJB example project running on an JBoss Application server.

Answer (score 0):

Here this [youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wjh0bMGkIwU) is your freind.

And a [sample Project](https://github.com/jdwyah/tocollege.net) on GIT Hub.

I am assuming you are Familiar with `GWT-RPC`